# Install meld on Rhel6.5 without root priviledges

Tags: bash, system, redhat, meld

I am trying to install the meld(https://meldmerge.org/) package into Rhel6.5. I found an rpm on rpmbone(http://rpm.pbone.net/info_idpl_16047923_distro_redhatel6_com_meld-1.4.0-1.el6.rf.noarch.rpm.html).

I do not have root privileges and internet access. Thus I try to use 'https://github.com/mathieucaroff/user-yum.sh' this repository to install the meld into my home directory.

After I installed the rpm with the 'user-yum', the meld could not start because of the following error.

`import meld.paths ImportError: No module named meld.paths`

Answer (score 1):

After I search the meld package, it requires python-site packages(https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2016-May/msg00007.html). And it is not possible to install meld as python package on the user environment on Rhel6.5.

Therefore, Instead of installing as an rpm, creating a bundle with all the required files solves the problem.

Download bundle [here](https://download.gnome.org/sources/meld/1.6/meld-1.6.0.tar.xz%22)!

Installation steps are:

1. Transfer the tar file to your home directory.
2. `tar -xf meld-1.6.0.tar.xz` - Extract files.
3. `cd ~/meld-1.6.0/bin` - Navigate the meld binary directory.
4. `echo "PATH=\"$(pwd):\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc` - Add current directory to path.
5. `source ~/.bashrc` - Source the bashrc.
6. `meld` - Run meld to verify.